# Ajax call when session time out

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

All, I am trying to redirect to login page if making a ajax call when session timeout. 
Here is what I had done so far.

Define a action filter for all the action.

```
public class AuthenticateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            var routeDataSet = filterContext.RouteData;
            if (LoginUser.LoginAdministrator == null)
            {
                //if the useinfo stored in session is timeout. 
                if (routeDataSet != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["controller"] != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login")
                    && routeDataSet.Values["action"] != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login"))
                {
                    //if it is login action itself.let it be. don't do anything.


                }
                else
                {
                    //redirect to login page.
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Login" }, { "action", "Login" } });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works for non ajax action call when session time out. But for the ajax call. It can't not redirect to login page but only return a html page string(seems it is the source html code for login page), not the really result.
Say we have code like this.

```
function ajaxGetLogDetail(logId) {
        var sUrl = "/LogDetail/index?logId=" + logId;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: sUrl,
            success: function (result) {
                //please note result is html string. not the really result.
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Could anyone help to give me some clue for solving this issue? thanks.

**Updated**

Based on the Mohsin and Dave's answer(thanks you two), Here is the finally solution. Please review it. thanks.

```
public class AuthenticateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            var routeDataSet = filterContext.RouteData;
            if (LoginUser.LoginAdministrator == null)
            {

                //&& routeDataSet != null && routeDataSet.Values["controller"] != null
                //&& !routeDataSet.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login") && routeDataSet.Values["action"] != null
                //&& !routeDataSet.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login") && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToLower().Equals("get"))
                if (routeDataSet != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["controller"] != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login")
                    && routeDataSet.Values["action"] != null
                    && routeDataSet.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login"))
                {



                }
                else
                {
                    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                        {
                            Data = new
                            {
                                ErrorMessage = "SystemSessionTimeOut"
                            },
                            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Login" }, { "action", "Login" } });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On the client side :

```
function ajaxGetLogDetail(logId) {
        var sUrl = "/LogDetail/index?logId=" + logId;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: sUrl,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.ErrorMessage=="SystemSessionTimeOut")
                {
                   windows.location="/Login/Login";
                } 
                else
                {
                   //...  
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you check for the request type using IsAjaxRequest in your view after getting redirected from the above filter and respond accordingly

Comment: Good Idea, Did you mean the `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest`? thanks.

Comment: Hi , Mohsin, Dave gave me more detail. So, the only way to make it is perform a client side redirect. I think it is the part of your mean .

Comment: "Ajax calls CANNOT return a redirect of any kind. At core an AJAX call only returns a string. There is no Engine of the kind that will perform a redirect." but who is saying to perform a redirect you may call the RedirectToAction and at the view toggle the rendering of the page also this may help you to easily redirect to the last web page after the login has been performed as you have total control on the request and can bypass the regular navigation practice

Comment: Hi , Mohsin, I think I can make to redirect to last web page after the login by this way : window.location='/Login/Login?lasturl=' + lastUrl; lastUrl stores the current view url.

Comment: Hi , Mohsin, Could you please review my updated content. thanks.

Comment: By last web page I meant to the page where user was before this ajax request was made. Now in this situation you have to follow the regular navigation sequence once the user logs in after session time out

Comment: looks right. I don't see the windows.location navigation. And yes, you can pass a param '/Login/Login?lasturl=' + lastUrl. The catch is you will need a route that includes lasturl. Routes are defined in Global.asax

Comment: ok.Thanks.need defined route indcludes `lasturl`? I thought `lasturl` is the parameter of `Login` action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ajax calls CANNOT return a redirect of any kind. At core an AJAX call only returns a string. There is no Engine of the kind that will perform a redirect.

You CAN perform a client side redirect though. If the Session has timed out and on client side have your Controller Method return false:

```
     if !(routeDataSet != null
         && routeDataSet.Values["controller"] != null
         && routeDataSet.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login")
         && routeDataSet.Values["action"] != null
         && routeDataSet.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("login"))
      {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = errorMessage });
      }
```

In your AJAX `error` function:

```
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            window.location='/Login/Login';
        }
```

**Side note:** was your destination meant to be '/Login/Login' or '/Account/Login'

Comment: Hi , Dave, Could you please review my updated content. thanks.