# Preventing jQuery modal popup from opening on session timeout MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, modal-dialog

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, in which I'm trapping session timeout in a session timeout filter handler to handle session timeouts. I also want to handle session timeout for ajax requests. I initially implemented the code I found in this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001280/ajax-call-when-session-time-out).

Which worked a treat initially for autocompletes and other ajax calls, but the only issue being for ajax calls to modal popups!

So now I have changed my session timeout handler to look like this :

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            var sessionStateDetails =(SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
            var sessionCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];

            if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf(sessionStateDetails.CookieName) >= 0))
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
```

i.e. setting the status code to 500 (401 didnt work for me cause I am using Windows authentication and impersonation so if I change status to 401, I get a security popup for password and username).

And then I trap this in either an .ajaxSetup , or .ajaxError I have tried both ...and re-direct to my session timeout action (as required) to display view with session timeout.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (xhr, props) {
    if (props.status === 500) {
        ////session redirect goes here 
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
        var segment_1 = pathArray[1];
        var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + segment_1 + "/Home/SessionTimeout";
        window.location = newURL;
    }
});
```

The problem is before the re-direct , the ajax popup is still briefly opened. So it doesnt look great. Any idea how I can prevent it opening at all and re-directing smoothly ?

Here is my jQuery dialog code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this)
            .attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                height: 'auto',
                show: 'fade',
                hide: 'fade',
                resizable: 'false'
            })
        .load(this.href);

    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, I think im almost there with this.

Comment: i have a solution but it's a little bit different : if you call an ajax request and your session is over, i'm opening a login dialog otherwise if it's normal request i redirect to login page. Are you interested ?

Comment: If you don't want the dialog to open, don't call the code to open the dialog until you have the ajax response that you're looking for.

Comment: Hi rossisdead , how would i do this ? Ive added my jquery modal code above now. How would i check this before running this up ? Sorry my jquery isnt great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working in the end , if anyone else is having the same issue , here is what i did ... i kept using the session handler , but i now raise a 403 instead of a 500 , as raising a 500 was obviously wrong and had a few undesirable side effects:

Code from

```
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

                }
                else ...usual code goes here ....
```

And then i trap the ajax error as follows:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (xhr, props) {
    if (props.status == 403 ) {
        ////session redirect goes here 
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
        var segment_1 = pathArray[1];
        var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + segment_1 + "/Home/SessionTimeout";
        window.location = newURL;
    }
});
```

Of course my popup still attempts to load for the briefest of moments before re-direct ,but my users dont seem to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your override `public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)` and use ( in global.asax):

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        HttpContextWrapper context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            context.Response.RedirectLocation = string.Empty;
        //MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }
```

and in your JavaScript :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ //jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        302: function () {
            __userLoginEvent = true;
        }
    }
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    if (__userLoginEvent) {
        //your redirection here

        __userLoginEvent = false;
    }
})
```

i use `ajaxStop` because if you are multiple ajax call you want one redirection. That's work perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks Olivier , i'll give this a try and let you know !

Comment: Thanks Oliver , this answer looked good but it didnt work for me , i ended up staying with my session timeout handler in the end ...